# Angular 7 CLI can not find runtime.js and the rest of .js files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 7 CLI with asp.net core 2.1

When deploying to azure the index.html produced is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ClientApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Can not find the .js files, they are located in the dist folder ...

Any suggestions?

Snippet from angular.json

```
ClientApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

Comment: I compare your config with my. Looks like everything fine. Maybe you have some trouble with access rights? If you try use IIS on your local machine is it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to solve.

I guess that you have one of these 2 below problems (or both of them):

**1. You created a paste inside your bucket.**

- Open your first web page inside your Azure bucket with your DNS with
     developer tools enabled.
- Check for your index.html full URL Example:
  https://youbucket.azure.com/yourpaste/index.html c. just open your
  index.html and alter the  to

**2. You don't have enough permissions to access all the files**
Try to give your storage and all your files public read access
You can follow the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

I hope it works man! ;)